# Как реализовать Timer

Tags: таймер, java

Есть ли в JAVA компонент, аналог компоненту Timer в Delphi?
Если нет, то как можно реализовать следующее:
нужно, чтобы через определенный интервал приложение издавало одиночный сигнал или вибрацию,  можно просто сообщение Toast.makeText(...) и опять запускало этот таймер.
Предвижу, что придется выделять это в отдельный поток, но пока не разобрался до конца, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа такого:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
```